# newline in json_encode() output

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am building an output array like so

```
            if (count($errors)) {
                $success = 'false'; 
                $output['json_msg'] = "Please try your submission again.";
                $output['errors'] = $errors;
            } else {
                $success = 'true';  
                $output['json_msg'] = "Thanks for Becoming a NOLA Insider!";
            }

            $output['success'] = $success;

            header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
            if (count($errors)) { http_response_code(500); }
            echo json_encode($output);          
            exit;
```

But when I look at the response in Chrome's Network pane of the developer tools I see what appears to be a newline in response:

[image: developer console screenshot]

I tried wrapping json_encode() in trim() but this gave garbled output.

How do I eliminate the carriage return?

Comment: Some time its due to white space before <?php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a `?>` at the end of your PHP file and what's happening when you remove it ?

Because you may have a carriage return at the end of the script which may be sent before your response :

```
?>\n
// END OF FILE
```

This is explained by the fact that PHP is actually a templating language :

Here is a file which defines a function and which displays a text :

```
<?php
/**
 * @File lib.php
 */
 function sayHello()
 {
     echo "hello";
 }
 ?>
 forgotten text
```

And here is a file that includes this file.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file index.php
 */
 include_once('lib.php');
 sayHello();
```

This will output :

```
forgotten text
hello
```

The "forgotten text" is output when the lib.php file is included whereas the "hello" is output after.

(But it may be even simpler and just the point that @nanocv suggested)

Comment: Thank you.  I had previously checked for this but have checked again now.  Nothing at all after ?>

Comment: There was a separate database connection file included.  It had a newline after ?> and once removed the issue was resolved.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can try to remove new line using `str_replace`

```
$output = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"),'',$output);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have added this and it preserves the JSON but I still have the return so clearly the \n is not in $output but elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the new line characters like `\r\n` to your json code after `json_encode()` you can follow up the method with the final `json_value` that you get. This will remove up all the new lines that has been output-ed from the code that you obtain after you perform the `json_encode()`.

Hence you need to `preg_replace()` the json outputed value as follows which will remove uo the new lines from the `json_code`.

This will replace the new lines with no value over to the second parameter in `preg_replace()`.

> Try not to provide any white spaced between the `php codes` (i.e) Opening and Closing Codes that you process either at the beginning or at the end of the document. This may cause the issue sometimes.

**Code:**

```
$output_json = preg_replace("!\r?\n!","", $output_json);
```

Answer (score 2):

I bet your php code starts this way:

```
1.            <--- Note the blank line here
2. <?php
```

That's a new line character that will became part of the result.

(This way I could recreate the same behavior)

[image]

Comment: I have been on lookout in code for exactly that issue but not found it.  Very first line has no space and <?php

Comment: Then I lost the bet! I had a very similar error before, and it was caused for that blank line so I thought it was the same case. I'm glad you solved it!

Answer (score -1):

I solved by removing spaces from the php file indicated in the `include` .

Comment: This is not new/valuable information on this page.  This occurrence is already covered by the accepted answer.